# Flow type refinement doesn't work if check null/undefined through another vairable

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In the following example (or on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0FDD0oAgAQMwGwPYHcQBcCeAHAphACggM4CWqxCAdhALwQDeAPsBBAB4BcEFArgLYBG2AE4AaZhHSceA4cAYBfEDG4UAxmUoQAhhQSoAFsIDClACalyFABQBKTvwQI4dcUOypuQqqiHdsAbmBFYGU1DSoAc3cASVRbTgB+AhJwlxY3Dy96DgB2EQlOAA5FYND1SwhCGLjMdmSLShsXYNVKQlQITCIaCCjUWNtA1op2iGJCAHkAax6uwggAMgXtXQNjMwbrG0Dx6cXlqv6aohsgA)) type refinement doesn't seem to work when we check null/undefined via another variable.

```
type Position = {|
  x: number,
  y: number
|}

function anotherCondition(): bool{
  return true;
}

function getIt(): ?Position{
  return {x:7, y: 8}
}

function setIt(p:Position){
}

const pos = getIt();
const isOk = pos && anotherCondition();
isOk && setIt(pos)
```

But if we do it inline without `isOk` variable, it works fine. But I have several places to check this condition and using a variable like `isOk` make it less verbose. Is there any way to make it work? or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `getIt` function returns an **optional** `Position`, which means that `flow` doesn't know if `pos` has a value or not.

In your example given, `getIt` should return a fixed `Position` like (see [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1ABVgM4CWKRsAdqALygDeAPoqKAB4Bco5ArgLYBGWAE4AaJqDQdu-IYnoBfZJC7kAxqQqgAhuVgoAFkIDCFACYky5ABQBKDn1ixodMYKwougyikFcsAbkQFRCVVdUoAczcASRQbDnxiMOdmV3dPZOZWNgB2UUzxDgAOPNAFIJC1C1ACaNiMeMJzCmtaQOQVCgIUUAxCBsSqmkiUGJsAjvIu0CICAHkAazsHaCxtah7CUAAyLa0dfSNTJqtrAJmF7d2akbrCU6A)):

```js
function getIt(): Position {
  return {
    x:7,
    y: 8,
  }
}
```

Since you know 100% sure that `pos` is of type `Position` (because `isOk` can only be `true` if that's the case), you can explicitly typecast it to `Position` (which is a dirty way, I know) like (see [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1ABVgM4CWKRsAdqALygDeAPoqKAB4Bco5ArgLYBGWAE4AaJqDQdu-IYnoBfZJC7kAxqQqgAhuVgoAFkIDCFACYky5ABQBKDn1ixodMYKwougyikFcsAbkQFRCVVdUoAczcASRQbDnxiMOdmV3dPZOZWNgB2UUzxDgAOPNAFIJC1C1ACaNiMeMJzCmtaQOQVCgIUUAxCBsSqmkiUGJsAjvIu0CICAHkAazsHaCxtah7CUAAyLa0dfSNTJqtrAMQZhe3dmpHYy0tegg5tNFs8RrDrU6A)):

```js
isOk && setIt(((pos: any): Position));
```

Comment: I want it to be optional. This is just an example. In the actual scenario, some cases, `getIt` might return null as well.

Comment: I've added an alternative you can do to my answer 

Comment: The problem is rather that flow's refinement algo is often hard to predict, as illustrated in the OP's example.

Comment: @ftor Indeed. I've had a bunch of dirty typecast myself, just because `flow` wasn't recognizing everything correct. This should be addressed sometimes I think, but right now, sticking to the dirty typecasts is the only alternative I fear. 

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I have already got rid of this with another kind of dirty way. So that's not what I'm looking for. I'm interested to know why this happens and what's the correct way to fix this. Now it seems like this is a limitation of flow.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara Maybe you can report this as an issue on the repo (and post the link here), so this can start to be addressed and people can add other examples the `flow` team can use to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on refinements, which are evidently frequently invalidated, you rather should define a union type that reflects both cases:

```
// @flow

type Position = {|
  x: number,
  y: number
|} | null

function anotherCondition(): bool{
  return true;
}

function getIt(): Position {
  const r = Math.random();
  return r <= 0.5 ? {x:7, y: 8} : null;
}

function setIt(p:Position){
  if (p) {}
  else {}
}

const pos = getIt();
setIt(pos);
```

Now, however, you have to take into account the different cases within the functions that except such a union type. This should still be more DRY.

I think you should avoid maybe types whenever possible and use the more accurate union types instead.